# Efficient way to add iterables in this simple Gpa calculator. Also 2 variables in 1 input?

Tags: python

I actually have 2 questions. So below is a simple GPA calculator.

1st question:I made one list for the gpa and one list for the credit. I then did sum(list) to add each element in each list up. Is this a proper/efficient way getting the sum of each category( gpa and credit)?

2nd question: In this code, I ask user to input their mark and credit in the line below. How would I get both values in 1 line seperated by a comma.So for example, 95,0.5. (I need everything to be a float)

I tried doing something like this but clearly it's wrong.

```
  mark,credit=float(input('mark'+ str(Markcount)+':','credit'+ str(Creditcount)+':').split(','))
```

Here's the entire code:

```
    GpaList=[]
    CreditList=[]
    Markcount=0
    Creditcount=0

print("Welcome to the GPA calculator.")   

courses=int(input("enter amount of courses"))

print('Enter marks in percentage and then credit for that course in the next line')

for a in range(courses):
    Markcount+=1
    Creditcount+=1
    mark=int(input('mark'+ str(Markcount)+':'))
    credit=float(input('credit'+ str(Creditcount)+':'))

    if mark>=85 and mark<=100:
        gpa=float(4.0)


    elif mark>=80 and mark<=84:
        gpa=float(3.7)

    elif mark>=77 and mark<=79:
        gpa=float(3.3)

    elif mark>=73 and mark<=76:
        gpa=float(3.0)

    elif mark>=70 and mark<=72:
        gpa=float(2.7)

    elif mark>=67 and mark<=69:
        gpa=float(2.3)

    elif mark>=63 and mark<=66:
        gpa=float(2.0)

    elif mark>=60 and mark<=62:
        gpa=float(1.7)

    elif mark>=57 and mark<=59:
        gpa=float(1.3)

    elif mark>=53 and mark<=56:
        gpa=float(1.0)

    elif mark>=50 and mark<=52:
        gpa=float(0.7)

    else:
        gpa=float(0.0)




    weightGpa= float(gpa*credit)
    (GpaList.append(weightGpa))
    (CreditList.append(credit))

    totalSum=float(sum(GpaList))
    totalCredit=float(sum(CreditList))
    FinalGpa=totalSum/totalCredit
    print(FinalGpa)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sum` idea for the first question is correct.

For the second question, this is how you could do it:

```
mark = float(input('mark'+ str(Markcount)+':'))
credit = float(input('credit'+ str(Creditcount)+':'))
```

If you want to take it from input in one piece, you could do this:

```
mark,credit = map(float, input('mark'+ str(Markcount)+' and credit'+ str(Creditcount)+':').split(','))
```

`map` applies the first argument, the function `float`, to each element in the second argument, which is an iterable.

Comment: Can you explain what is map doing here? Isn't map used to return a list? What was wrong with my attempt?

Comment: @Angular: I mistakenly left out an important piece of information. `map` does return something like a list, though you have to do `list(map(...))` to see it in list form. There were two things wrong with your attempt: 1) you tried to apply `float` to a list, when it only works on strings and numbers, and 2) you tried to give `input` multiple arguments in a way that it's not meant to be used.